# How to tell Wolfram to do this?

Tags: code-request

For a positive integer $N$, let $T(N)$ denote the number of arrangements of the integers $1, 2, \cdots N$ into a sequence $a_1, a_2, \cdots a_N$ such that $a_i > a_{2i}$ for all $i$, $1 \le i < 2i \le N$ and $a_i > a_{2i+1}$ for all $i$, $1 \le i < 2i+1 \le N$. For example, $T(3)$ is $2$, since the possible arrangements are $321$ and $312$ . Is there a way to possibly get all the arrangements for a general N ? That is $T(N)$ ? I am not able make a code for the same , is it possible to get the all possible values till N<=1000 ?

Comment: This is not really a question about Mathematica and the Wolfram language though. You may want to ask it in the math forum instead: https://math.stackexchange.com and once you have a method to solve your problem, we can help you implement it in Mathematica.

Comment: Okay sure @MarcoB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: This just demonstrates how to check a list for the property described**

You could proceed along these lines.

Chunk the list into the comparison "partners". The first item will never be on the right hand side of a comparison. So, we can partition into pairs excluding the first item.

```
Partition[Rest@list, 2, 2, {1, 1}, {}]
```

Now, the left hand sides of the comparisons can only be taken from the front half of the list, so let's get that sublist.

```
Take[list, Floor[Length@list/2]]
```

With these two derived structures we can now pair up their elements. The left sides will be single numbers, and the right sides will be pairs (or possibly a singleton at the last position). Next we want to do a Greater comparison of the left side to each member of the right side. I don't think there's a built in function for this, so I'll define one.

```
GreaterAll[{n_, ns_List}] := And @@ Thread[Greater[n, ns]]
```

We can map this over the structure we built and then wrap the result in And. Putting this all together into a function:

```
PropertyCheck[ints_List] :=
  And @@ 
    Map[
      GreaterAll, 
      Transpose@
        {Take[ints, Floor[Length@ints/2]], Partition[Rest@ints, 2, 2, {1, 1}, {}]}]
```

Now, if your lists are going to be very long, we might want to take a more imperative approach.

Comment: oops, I didn't notice your last requirement about N up to 1000. I thought you just needed to check a given list. To generate all lists that satisfies the requirement would be a different thing...

Comment: Its okay my main consideration was how to write the setup , and you mostly explained it and i understood thanks